# Catch Sencha CMD command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, extjs, sencha-cmd

I am trying to automate our build process on Sencha with the PowerShell script. If an error was encountered during the sencha package build or sencha app build I am hoping the PowerShell can catch it, but it didn't.

Here's a sample of my code.

```
try {
        sencha package build
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Woops error"
    }
```

Even though an error was encountered on the sencha package build, it appears that it treated it like a success function call. My guess is that sencha cmd uses ANT?

Now, is it possible to catch the sencha package build log in the PowerShell script?

I hope anyone can help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if Sencha actuallt throws exceptions, but what happens if you put `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` **above** the try block?

Comment: Hello. I tried this already but it didn't work :(

Comment: Can't you parse the output of the command for `[ERR]`?

Comment: Hi @incutonez, I was able to come up with a weird solution I think it's the same as your suggestion. I put the command in a variable and throw if the returned value contains `[ERR]`. It goes like this `$output = sencha package build $errMsg = $output | Where-Object { $_.Contains("[ERR]") } | Out-String`. If you have a better idea, please let me know :)